# Can I cut out a leak, in the middle of a stainless braided water line, and splice it back, under the kitchen sink?

Tags: plumbing, leaking, splicing, stainless

How can I cut a leak out of the middle of a stainless, braided **water line** and splice back together under my kitchen sink?

Comment: Please post photos of the braided supply line connection to/in your faucet. In recent years, many faucets have been made with braided supply lines permanently attached (to cut costs and simplify installation). If a braided line leaks on one of these, the whole faucet must be replaced. Perhaps you have one of these.

Comment: not economically viable to repair

Comment: The braided cover is a cosmetic McGuffin. It's a bit of plastic hose, and even /looking/ at it with the light of repair in your eyes will make matters far, far worse.

Comment: Even if Sharkbite supported doing these (which they don't) that would likely be more expensive for that splicer than a new line entirely.

Comment: I would look more closely at the source of the leak. It seems strange for a leak to develop in the middle of a braided supply line. The weak points are usually the connections above or below the line.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd I always thought the braiding was to provide strength, not to actually hold the water--the idea making it much less likely to burst over the decades.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I'm not sure it's strength as much as protection from abrasion etc. What it doesn't protect against is twisting due to sloppy assembly.

Comment: I definitely think @user2448131 is on to something here. Are you 100% certain that the leak is in the middle of the line and not at one of the fittings at either end and it's just dripping off a low point that happens to be somewhere between the ends? In either case, replacement is the only realistic way to go, but you may want to carefully look at both threaded ends to ensure there isn't thread damage on a part that you're _not_ planning on replacing.

Comment: Also, please do _not_ post your "pictures as a fix" - that's not how this site works - if you'll take the [tour] (and register your account while you're at it), you'll learn more about that.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Unless you have a considerable array of specialized hose-crimping equipment -

### No, they are disposable, not repairable.

Comment: Replacing was my first thought. Disconnected compression fitting at lower end (feed end) near shut off. Then followed hose up through sink and countertop into faucet. Very hard to reach behind deep sink basin. Just wondering if something like an AN fitting for braided hose in car engines existed for braided water line too

Comment: Also top end of braided water line is connected in faucet. Ill have to take that off it looks like. If you all think that's my best option? Thanks!

Comment: I've never heard of AN fittings before but having looked at them now I'd say a union fitting would cost more than a new water supply hose, and installing it, both sides, on a hose that remains connected at one end, inside a cupboard, would be more frustrating than replacing the entire sink!

Comment: Thanks to all answers! I will post pictures as fix today. I believe i do have a new faucet where braided hoses came from manufacturer already attached. Looks like ill have to price replacement of entire faucet. Will keep this site posted. Thanks so much again to all for support!

Comment: I have a faucet like yours that came with two braided hoses already attached, but I had no issue finding a replacement hose. I needed a longer one, the original was otherwise OK.

Comment: Beating a dead horse here, but just a reminder that if *one* part of a hose failed, *another* part isn’t far behind. (Plus, the adjacent hose is the same age, right?)

Answer (score 17):

Totally agree with other answers. Replace the leaking jacketed flexible faucet supply line. These things are not that expensive. A typical 12 inch or 16 inch Braided Stainless Steel Flexible Faucet Supply Line at Lowes has a price less than $10 (not much more than you may pay for a large size fancy coffee at the coffee shop).

Another thing to consider is that the original connection lines for HOT and COLD were probably installed at the same time. It would be wise to replace both with new seeing as one has failed the other may be near to that condition as well.

Answer (score 9):

You probably could do that and have it last for a few minutes. By the time you found the proper size rubber connector and hose clamps, you'd have spent more than buying a new supply line. And that doesn't include trying to repair the stainless steel brading. don't be penny wise and pound foolish. Buy a new one.

Comment: And that's assuming the OP could even find the leak in the first place. As a comment on the question states, the wire braid is just a covering, so that would likely to have to be fully removed to even begin looking for the leak. Doing that without creating a new leak by nicking the inner pipe with the tools required to cut through the wire braid would likely take longer than driving to a store, buying a new one, and driving back. That assuming the OP has the at least one of the various tools it would take to cut the braid. Fixing this hose has a massive opportunity for failure.

Comment: agreed JACK, just replace it, they are not that expensive and even if the OP could find the needed parts, they would probably come close to the price of a complete replacement.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  Hi ... what are you doing up so early on saturday???

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a stainless steel water line.

That is a rubber/plastic water line with a stainless steel jacket, as you have figured out.  The stainless' job is to a) look good, and b) protect from a limited degree of physical, radiant and chemical damage.

But at the end of the day it's still a rubber/plastic line and **will age as such**.

The stainless outer wrap gets in the way of any economical repair.

Comment: They also protect against damage by animals.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you have to ascertain *exactly* where the pipe has a leak, cut it there, cut the braid both sides, giving room for two clamps, insert a solid walled tube that was a good internal fit, tighten up said clamps, only to find that all the manipulation has caused another leak further along the pipe.

In that time, you could have bought and fitted a new pipe. Which would then last as long again as the leaking one. So why bother??

Comment: the braiding is for strength because I have seen the hose burst because the braiding got very rusty if the house is by the ocean. I prefer to use the ones that have the strength inside the clear plastic.

Comment: @FrankO'Donnell - I have a suspicion that the rusty braid affected the plastic itself, causing a weak spot which leaked. Perhaps we'll never know!

Answer (score 0):

The faucets that come with fitted supply lines are not necessarily "permanently attached". The makers put them in there somehow. I have changed these in two different designs in the past few months.

Case 1: The flexies are a hand-tight screw thread (with two O-rings each), and the braided cover is strong enough to tighten and loosen them.

You can even do this behind a deep sink, although fishing for the thread can be frustrating. I found they came in 8mm, 10mm, 12mm threads, and buying the right one can be difficult. My supplier was helpful enough to try them all.

Case 2: The flexies are retained in the faucet by a slotted W plate and sealed by O-rings. So if you try to unscrew these, they will turn either way, but not loosen.

The whole internal assembly can be taken out from the top, by taking off any handle and decorative cover, then finding a brass screwed ring or similar. With that removed, the entire works can be pushed up using the flexies. Watch the alignment of all the parts as they come out, and lay them out in the exact order for reassembly (which took me three shots anyway).

The final block to come out has a slotted plate screwed on from underneath, which retains the flexies into the block. In this case, the new flexies might only be available from the makers.

Incidentally, the main purpose of the braided cover is mechanical support for the plastic inner pipe. Hot water under pressure in narrow plastic pipe is kinda stretchy.