# Replace connector on one end of steel-jacketed faucet supply line?

Tags: bathroom, faucet

I started out looking here: [Can I cut out a leak, in the middle of a stainless braided water line, and splice it back, under the kitchen sink?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/266023/can-i-cut-out-a-leak-in-the-middle-of-a-stainless-braided-water-line-and-splic). Everyone tends to just answer "it's not economical--just replace it". But on my faucet, as far as I can tell, the hoses are permanently attached--they cannot be replaced. The faucet is designed to be installed in a single hole in the sink, so the hoses just dangle out the bottom of the faucet. I've disassembled the faucet and examined where the hoses are connected to the mixing valve. They are not screwed onto it. They are clamped on. There does not appear to be any way to remove them.

The connector at the end of my cold water hose has a tiny crack in it. So my thought is to just cut the line above the connector and splice on a new connector. But my research hasn't revealed that it's possible to do so, nor has it found any kind of connector that I can purchase with the intent to splice it onto a hose. Does such a thing exist?

(Yes, the faucet is under warranty, but they want a receipt, and I can't find it.)

Comment: It's very unlikely that your hoses are attached. Pics or model information, please.

Comment: Pics of _your_ actual installation will help. Someone here might see where the hoses disconnect while you miss them. That's why we ask for help - others see things we don't...

Comment: @isherwood actually, for a kitchen faucet—especially the single handle center set—it is *very* likely that the hoses are attached to the faucet, since they have to run up the threaded tube.  OP isn't talking about *supply* hoses, AFAICT.

Comment: Those are usually solid copper or plastic. This sounds like upstream supplies. Still waiting for clarification....

Comment: @isherwood have a look at the faucet in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unFBrfqYWOM

Comment: I did say "usually". _Still_ waiting for carlification.... This speculation is pointless. :)

Comment: American Standard. The box says "Chatfield 7413101.002" I'll add a picture when I can. Hooked it back up just to the hot so the bathroom wouldn't be completely without water, so I'll have to take it all apart again to take pictures.